# VBA Userform Textbox - How to return to default border style upon changing it

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm creating a VBA UserForm in Excel 2010. I've added a bunch of textboxes like so:

[image]

Let's say I selected the top textbox and looked at its properties. The `BorderStyle` is set to `0-fmBorderStyleNone`. Upon changing the `BorderStyle` to `1-fmBorderStyleSingle` and then back to `0-fmBorderStyleNone`, it loses its default style, like the top textbox shown below:

[image]

This is using the object. If I were to edit the `BorderStyle` using VBA code, the effect is the same.

Is there a way to get back the fully default `BorderStyle` of the textbox after changing the BorderStyle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually property `SpecialEffect` that controls to sunken look.  Changing `BorderStyle` also affects `SpecialEffect`

To reset, change `SpecialEffect` to `frmSpecialEffectSunken`

Comment: Thanks! It's a little bit embarrassing that I didn't bother looking at the documentation for BorderStyle, as it is explained there. At least future users may find this useful.